# Is there a way to printf $@ verbatim?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I want to write a script that echoes to `stdout` its `$@` verbatim, including any potential double-quotes, without a newline.

What I have tried:

```
> cat ./script1    
#! /usr/bin/bash
printf "%s %s" $0 $@
echo -n $0 $@
echo -n "$0 $@"
> 
> ./script1 a "bc d"
./script1 abc d./script1 a bc d./script1 a bc d>
```

I would like my script to run as follows:

```
> ./script1 a "bc d"
./script1 a "bc d">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your positional parameters do not contain any double quotes in your example:

```
./script1 a "bc d"
```

The double quotes there are simply to tell the shell that no word splitting should be performed on the space between `bc` and `d`.

If you want your second parameter to contain literal quotes you need to escape them to tell the shell they are literals:

```
./script1 a '"bc d"'
```

or

```
./script1 a \"bc\ d\"
```

You can use `printf` to print them in a format that can reused as shell input (escaped):

```
$ set -- a "bc d"
$ printf '%q\n' "$@"
a
bc\ d
```

As you can see this only escapes the space though.

Comment: I see...so it sounds like the double-quotes are "intercepted" by the shell before it even reaches the script. Is that "just the way it is" or is there any workaround to that, so that the script might function per my hypothetical perfect script?

Comment: @StoneThrow: That is how it works, your quotes are to tell the shell how to interpret the arguments presented on the command line and what the final command is.  If you want literal quotes to be passed into your script you must escape them as I have described in my answer.

Comment: @StoneThrow: This is similar to how your script can't print out exactly how long you held down each key when typing your command line, or how many times you hit backspace. Just as the command line you execute doesn't contain exact keystroke information, the arguments the script receives don't include exact command line information.

Answer (score 5):

As has been explained elsewhere, the double quotes you type are indications to the shell that the enclosed text is to be treated as a single word. If you want to print out the words surrounded by quotes that's fairly straightforward; you just need to include them in the text that you output:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '"%s" ' "$@"
printf "\n"
```

Note that this will add double quotes to every argument, not just those that might have had them when you ran the command.